# Pandas read the chat log log json to data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to converting the multiple list to data frame. below list contains the details about cloud containers want to extract the information like name , language , description and workspace id.

```
{'workspaces': [{'name': 'A_SupportAgent_dev',
   'language': 'en',
   'metadata': {'api_version': {'major_version': 'v1',
     'minor_version': '2019-02-28'},
    'digressions': True},
   'description': 'Credit Card Banking Support Agent to assist with Sales And Service, created by Oliver Ivanoski and Steve Green',
   'workspace_id': '',
   'learning_opt_out': False},
  {'name': 'Neatnik Watson Assistant Webhook Demo Skill',
   'language': 'en',
   'metadata': {'api_version': {'major_version': 'v1',
     'minor_version': '2019-02-28'}},
   'webhooks': [{'url': 'https://neatnik.net/watson/assistant/webhook/',
     'name': 'main_webhook',
     'headers': []}],
   'description': '',
   'workspace_id': '',
   'system_settings': {'tooling': {'store_generic_responses': True},
    'system_entities': {'enabled': True},
    'spelling_auto_correct': True},
   'learning_opt_out': False}]
 'pagination': {'refresh_url': '/v1/workspaces?version=2019-02-28'}}
```

Want to convert the above list below data frame

[image]

Tried

```
pd.DataFrame(list(Workspace_List.items()) ,columns=['workspaces', 'pagination'])
columns = list(Workspace_List.keys())
values = list(Workspace_List.values())
arr_len = len(values)
```

Comment: What is the current output? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(Workspace_List['workspaces']) ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify columns as you have another dictionary. So i think following below code will help u to organize your desire output

```
key = ['name','language','description','workspace_id']
output = pd.DataFrame(columns = key)

for i in range(len(df['workspaces'])):
    ll = df['workspaces'][i]
    output.loc[i] = [ll[x] for x in key]
```